# Servidor APACHE CON PHP en producción, se desea incluir ciertas páginas con django. Causa problema en direccionamientos?

Tags: php, python, django, python-3.x, apache

Estoy por subir un proyecto de `django` que esta en ambiente de desarrollo a un ambiente de producción que ya tiene un tiempo. Este servidor esta bajo `apache` y `php`.

Lo que quiero saber es que si algún direccionamiento o redireccionamiento va a ser perdido en el servidor de producción por usar el complemento `mod_wsgi` de `django` para `apache`.

Pienso yo que con este modulo de `wsgi`, Apache tendría una jerarquía tipo: primero lo configurado en su propio servicio html y en caso de no encontrar nada, busca lo que el complemento wsgi con django tiene en el proyecto.

Lamentablemente no encuentro una respuesta concisa a esto.

En caso de no ser así, quisiera saber si hay alguna solución alterna para realizar lo propuesto anteriormente (subir un proyecto de django a un ambiente de producción que ya trabaja sin necesidad de pasar todo a django).

Comment: hola, @JackNavaRow, estoy pensando en usar virtualhost, también pienso que se trabajarian como servidores distintos y no habría problema. En todo caso el virtualhost X que contendría el enlace con django, sería llamado desde aluna parte del virtualhost Y, haciendo que no existan problemas en los direccionamientos y redireccionamientos que tiene actualmente el virtualhost Y. Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: correcto, no debes de tener problemas de redireccionamientos porque a final de cuentas son dominios distintos, de igual forma te recomuendo clonar la maquina y hacer la prueba para mi no va a haber problemas suponiendo que solo vas a agregar 1 modulo de apache y crear  y publicar un virtualhost adicional

Comment: la Maquina A seria la que esta publica que tiene dominio a.com y b.com , cuando entran a b.com realiza configuran un vhost de apache para redireccionar a otra maquina dentro de la red

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias! Estare implementando pronto y subiré la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contestando a lo anterior.

Se pidio soporte a Red Hat finalmente.

La configuración sigue de la manera en que describí anteriormente. Cabe destacar que no es la más indicada y que de ser posible se actualice el servidor a red hat 7 para ser compatible con nuevas tecnologías.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Suele ser recomendable separar los entornos en diferentes lenguajes. Para esto tienes varias opciones, bien por software como por ejemplo docker, en diferentes contenedores, o bien por hardware, separándolo en máquinas diferentes. Todo esto por temas de estabilidad.

Por otra parte, esta el tema del enrutamiento. Esto depende principalemente si lo vas a gestionar con dos dominios diferentes (y dos virtual host) o son subdominios o carpetas.
En el segundo caso influye mucho las reglas de redirecciones que tengas y, si estas utilizando un CMS o tu aplicación tiene router en general, el funcionamiento del mismo.

En el caso de los CMS en especial, efectivamente tendrás problemas ya que, cualquier ruta que no tengan en su base de datos te lanzará un 404. Será necesario crear una regla en apache para que no redirija en el subdirectorio donde coloques la aplicación de Django.

Comment: Entendido @JDaniel intentaré por virtualhosts para no tener varias computadores trabajando.